# Changing variable values on href with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm implementing a PHP function to translate my website based on HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, but also by user choice:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($language)) {
$language = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$language = strtolower(substr(chop($language[0]),0,2));
}

include("functions/content_".$language.".php"); 
?>
```

User choice comes when the user clicks a link in the navbar, like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="portfolio.php?language=es">Español</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.php?language=en">Enshlish</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.php?language=fr">Français</a></li>
</ul>
```

Problem is I can't get to change the value of $language with the hrefs, it always self-defines as "es" (my browser is set to Spanish).

Comment: try `$language = $_GET['language'];` (register_globals is probably off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
$language = isset($_GET['language']) ? $_GET['language'] : false;
if(!$language) {
    $language = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    $language = strtolower(substr(chop($language[0]),0,2));
}
```

Also, you can use a function (a helper function), like

```
function setlanguage()
{
    $language = isset($_GET['language']) ? $_GET['language'] : false;
    if(!$language) {
        $language = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
        $language = strtolower(substr(chop($language[0]),0,2));
    }
    return $language;
}
```

Use it like

```
$language = setlanguage();
include("functions/content_".$language.".php");
```

Comment: i like to use `if(isset($_GET['language']))` so the page doesn't generate an apache error every time it loads without the $_GET var set

Comment: @JoeT, It's better now, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

are you getting the value of $language before checking whether it's set?  With register_globals off you need to get it from the $_GET variable to get it from the URL:

`if(isset($_GET['language'])){ $language = $_GET['language']; }`